# How to get the body of a push notification sent from Firebase console in iOS 10 and Swift 3?

Tags: ios, firebase, swift3, ios10, firebase-notifications

I'm developing an iOS app that should receive push notifications sent from the Firebase console. I'm using Swift 3 and iOS 10.

As recommended by the Firebase documentation, we must assign our delegate object to the `UNUserNotificationCenter` object to receive and display notifications, and the `FIRMessaging` object to receive data messages, before our app finishes launching.

This has been done in the `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` method. I followed all the steps in order to configure Firmessaging as well as APNs.

Now, when I send a message from the Firebase console, I receive it through `applicationReceivedRemoteMessage(_ remoteMessage: FIRMessagingRemoteMessage)` method.

The problem is that I could not extract the body of the message from the `remoteMessage.appData` dictionary. Knowing that the body is within `remoteMessage.appData["notification"]`. Indeed, the instruction

```
print(remoteMessage.appData)
```

prints

```
[AnyHashable("notification"): {
   body = Hello Notifications;
   e = 1;
}, AnyHashable("from"): 49679924394, AnyHashable("collapse_key"): com.company.app]
```

Printing

```
 remoteMessage.appData["notification"]
```

shows

```
{
   body = Hello Notifications;
   e = 1;
}
```

I tried

```
remoteMessage.appData["notification"]["body"]
```

and

```
 remoteMessage.appData["notification"].body
```

but it results in syntax error. I could not extract the body in order to show it in an alert controller. The code of the appDelegate is given below.

```
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate, FIRMessagingDelegate, UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate{
......

func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions, launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
    application.isStatusBarHidden = true
    FIRApp.configure()
    FIRDatabase.database().persistenceEnabled = true
    if #available(iOS 10.0, *) {
       let authOptions : UNAuthorizationOptions = [.alert, .badge, .sound]
       let center = UNUserNotificationCenter.current()
       center.requestAuthorization(options: authOptions, completionHandler: {_ ,_ in })
       application.registerForRemoteNotifications()
// For iOS 10 display notification (sent via APNS)
       UNUserNotificationCenter.current().delegate = self
// For iOS 10 data message (sent via FCM)        
       FIRMessaging.messaging().remoteMessageDelegate = self         
    } else {
       let settings: UIUserNotificationSettings = UIUserNotificationSettings(types: [.alert, .badge, .sound], categories: nil)
       application.registerUserNotificationSettings(settings)
    }
    application.registerForRemoteNotifications()
     return true
}
// Receive data message on iOS 10 devices.
func applicationReceivedRemoteMessage(_ remoteMessage: FIRMessagingRemoteMessage) {
    print(remoteMessage.appData)
    print(remoteMessage.appData["notification"]!)
    let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "Message from IOBird Developer Team", message: "?????? Body of the message ?????", preferredStyle: .alert)
    let OKAction = UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .default) { (action:UIAlertAction!) in
    }
    alertController.addAction(OKAction)
    self.window?.rootViewController?.present(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Thanks Arthur Thompson for your help, you gave me the idea. I post the answer in case someone else need it. I wrote

```
let d : [String : Any] = remoteMessage.appData["notification"] as! [String : Any]
let body : String = d["body"] as! String
print(body)
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to retrieve the body using something like:

```
let body = remoteMessage.appData["notification"]!["body"] as! String
print(body)
```

Comment: I tried this instruction but remoteMessage.appData["notification"] is not a dictionary

Comment: I see, sorry try: remoteMessage.appData[AnyHashable("notification")]!

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to print any line from the response with this :

```
let response = remoteMessage.appData

print(response[AnyHashable("notification")] as Any)
```

Apple documentation on AnyHashable : https://developer.apple.com/reference/swift/anyhashable

Answer (score 0):

I had exactly the same problem with Firebase messaging and extracting the data and this works like a charm. (Swift 3)

```
    print("====")
    let d : [String : Any] = remoteMessage.appData["notification"] as! [String : Any]
    let body : String = d["body"] as! String
    let click_action : String = d["click_action"] as! String
    let title : String = d["title"] as! String
    print(body)
    print(title)
    print(click_action)
    print("=====")
```

Answer (score 0):

the best way

```
    func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter,
          didReceive response: UNNotificationResponse,
          withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping () -> Void) {
      let userInfo = response.notification.request.content.userInfo
      // Print message ID.
      if let messageID = userInfo[gcmMessageIDKey] {
        print("Message ID: \(messageID)")
      }
       UNUserNotificationCenter.current().delegate = self as UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate


       let apsData = (userInfo["order_id"] as? NSString)?.integerValue
       let d : [String : Any] = userInfo["aps"] as! [String : Any]
       let nh : [String : Any] = d["alert"] as! [String : Any]
   
       let body : String = nh["body"] as! String
       let title : String = nh["title"] as! String
   
       print(body,title)

       
       // if you need to go some views
       if apsData != nil {
           let sb = UIStoryboard(name: "Order", bundle: nil)
           let vc = sb.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "RequestDeliveriesVC") as! RequestDeliveriesVC
           vc.order_ofer = apsData ?? 0

           let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate

           guard  let window = appDelegate.window else {return}
           window.rootViewController = vc

           UIView.transition(with: window, duration: 0.5, options: .transitionCrossDissolve, animations: nil, completion: nil)
       } else {
        
       }
    
      print(userInfo)
      


      completionHandler()
    }

   }
```