# TabItem with BadgeValue only shows up when I launch the app from the notification trigger

Tags: ios, swift3, push-notification, apple-push-notifications, ios10

I have an app with push notifications using PHP EasyAPNS notification working fine on Swift 3, iOS 10. But one thing I can't understand is why the badge on TabItem is works fine when I launch the app from the notification alert but not when I open the app direct from the app icon (with the red Badge)

So here is the code that I use on AppDelegate:

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [String:Any])
{
    print("Message details \(userInfo)")

    if let aps = userInfo["aps"] as? NSDictionary
    {
        if let alertMessage = aps["alert"] as? String {
            let rootViewController = self.window?.rootViewController as! UITabBarController!
            let tabArray = rootViewController?.tabBar.items as NSArray!
            let tabItem = tabArray?.object(at: 3) as! UITabBarItem
            tabItem.badgeValue = "1"

            let myAlert = UIAlertController(title: "Message", message: alertMessage, preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.alert)
            let okAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Ok", style: UIAlertActionStyle.default, handler: nil)
            myAlert.addAction(okAction)
            self.window?.rootViewController?.present(myAlert, animated: true, completion: nil)
        }
    }
}
```

So, when I click in the alert to open my app, the badge is fine like this:

[image: TabItem Badge working]

But when I open the app using the icon itself, the badge is not showing up:

[image: TabItem Badge NOT working]

Anyone have any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Please let me know if I can improve the question!

Comment: Not sure if this has anything to do with your problem, but he function you're using is **deprecated**. You shouldn't be using this function in iOS10. If it works it's because you're lucky. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37956482/registering-for-push-notifications-in-xcode-8-swift-3-0) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39883112/how-to-get-the-body-of-a-push-notification-sent-from-firebase-console-in-ios-10).

Comment: In iOS10, if you want to have a callback when user **taps** then you must use [`didReceiveNotificationResponse`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/usernotifications/unusernotificationcenterdelegate/1649501-usernotificationcenter?language=objc)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be using the `application(_:didReceiveRemoteNotification:fetchCompletionHandler:)` method to handle notifications. As mentioned in the docs ([found here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiapplicationdelegate/1623013-application)), this method is called whether the app is in the foreground or background.

Also worth noting from the docs for `application(_:didReceiveRemoteNotification:)`

> If the app is not running when a remote notification arrives, the
>   method launches the app and provides the appropriate information in
>   the launch options dictionary. The app does not call this method to
>   handle that remote notification.

Note, if the app was not running and the user taps on the icon, the app will call `application(_:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:)`. There will be appropriate launchOption key-value pairs if the app had a remote notification which needs handling.

Comment: i am getting error when i click on notifications to go to a particular view controller in swift 3 , error i:-could not cast value of type 'UINavigationController' (0x3a79b0a0) to 'UITabBarController' (0x3a79b938)  app crashes @lostIn Transit

Comment: Well that would be something in your code. You are getting a `UINavigationController` but trying to use it as a `UITabBarController`. Check your implementation. And this should probably go as another question. It is not related to notifications.

Comment: could u help me with this @lostIn Transit