# Extract data from nested JSON in Firebase remoteMessage

Tags: json, swift, firebase, google-cloud-messaging, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am developing a messaging app in swift. I configured firebase cloud messaging and it works, the data arrives to my phone.

```
func messaging(_ messaging: Messaging, didReceive remoteMessage: MessagingRemoteMessage) {
    print(remoteMessage.appData)
}
```

Problem is, I don't know how to extract each value. This is a example of output I receive from the server.

```
[AnyHashable("message"): {"chat":{"msg":"hey","file":null,"to":"username","date":"2019\/03\/06 08:17:42","group":"TESTING","from":"User Real Name","res":"1"}}, AnyHashable("from"): 123123123]
```

I've tried reading it as a JSON but it doesn't work.

```
let data = try? JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: remoteMessage.appData["message"]
if let messageJSON = try? JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!) as? [String : Any] {
    print(messageJSON
    if let chatJSON = messageJSON["chat"] as? [String : Any] {
        print(chatJSON)
    }
}
```

It gives me this error on the first line.

> *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '*** +[NSJSONSerialziation dataWithJSONObject:options:error:]: Invalid top-level type in JSON write'

I followed the suggestions on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39883112/how-to-get-the-body-of-a-push-notification-sent-from-firebase-console-in-ios-10) post, but no luck either.

```
let d: [String : Any] = remoteMessage.appData["message"] as! [String : Any]
let body: [String : Any] = d["chat"] as! [String : Any]
let msg: String = body["msg"] as! String
print(msg)
```

> Could not cast value of type '__NSCFString' (0x1e0e52f90) to 'NSDictionary' (0x1e0e53bc0).

Comment: The error message clearly states that the value for key `message` is a string rather than a dictionary. And never `try?` when dealing with JSON decoding. **Catch** errors, they will help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need

```
do {
  let d  = remoteMessage.appData["message"] as! String
  let res = try JSONDecoder().decode(Root.self,from:Data(d.utf8)) 
  print(res)
}
catch {
 print(error)
}
```

---

```
struct Root: Codable {
    let chat: Chat
}

struct Chat: Codable {
    let msg: String
    let file: String?
    let to, date, group, from: String
    let res: String
}
```

as `message` key contains a json String not a dictionary